# SQL DATETIME Insert from Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel

So im having a rather strange problem, I have a Column (lets say Column A) in excel that has data that looks like this:

4/11/2015 10:14

I have a bunch of other columns, but anyways in my SQL Insert statement within excel, the data (when copying out) looks like this:
42105.4561921296

The ="INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('"&A1&"', Etc....)" is in the data format of "general" and the Date column is in the format of "Custom" where there is a M/DD/YYYY MM/HH type within.

The SQL Column is of the data type DATETIME, so it of course doesn't accept the weird number it gets.

Any ideas? changing the format of the "SQL INSERT" column doesn't change the results.

Comment: First try setting both data formats to text, and see if SQL will do the implicit  datetime conversion for you.

Comment: Unfortunately setting the actual date/time column to text gives the ugly number mentioned above. But I tried that anyways with no luck :/

Comment: What if you try changing the Excel format of your date column to Date/Time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are right - Excel formats only changes the way the numbers are **displayed**, not the underlying value of the cell. In this case, the value of the cell is an excel date-time value, which is the # of days since 1/1/1900, with decimals for the time.

I'd recommend using Excel's `TEXT` function to convert Excel's numeric date-time value to a text string that can be inserted into SQL:

Instead of:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('"&A1&"', Etc....)"
```

Try:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('"&TEXT(A1,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM")&"', Etc...)"
```

Comment: mind you that the codes in second argument of the text function (inside the double codes) is tied to your computer's system locale. if the above context doesn't work, check the corresponding cell's number format for your variant

Answer (score 4):

The best format to insert a date time into a datetime column is to present the date and time as YYYY-MM-DD Minute:Second or 2015-04-15 12:52

so to insert a datetime from Excel you can use this set of Excel functions:
(where A1 contains the datetime to be saved)

```
=YEAR(A1)&"-"&RIGHT("00"&MONTH(A1),2)&"-"&RIGHT("00"&DAY(A1),2)&" "&RIGHT("00"&HOUR(A1),2)&":"&RIGHT("00"&MINUTE(A1),2)&":"&RIGHT("00"&SECOND(A1),2)
```

Comment: you missed the hour, plus single digit values should contain leading zeros. i'm modifying your answer accordingly

Comment: create table #x1 (d1 datetime)
  insert into #x1 values ('2015-04-15 12:52')
  select * from #x1 returns this: 2015-04-15 12:52:00.000

Comment: that's hours and minutes with the seconds omitted, not minutes and seconds with the hour omitted