# VBA datetime format and import to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, datetime, datetime-format

i have a little problem with datetime format from VBA to SQL server 2008 R2, because imported datetime is only date like this:

```
2020-08-10 00:00:00.000
```

I want:

```
2020-08-10 09:15:30.000
```

Here is my VBA code:

```
Sub Data_transform()
Sheets("Poz_data").Range("A:P").NumberFormat = "General"
Sheets("Poz_data").Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Sheets("Poz_data").Range("H:H").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Sheets("Poz_data").Range("J:J").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Sheets("Poz_data").Range("K:K").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Sheets("Poz_data").Range("O:O").NumberFormat = "0"
End Sub

Sub Data_import()
             
Dim colum_a As Long
Dim colum_h As Long
Dim colum_j As Long
Dim colum_k As Long
Dim colum_s As Long
              
colum_a = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 1).Value
colum_b = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 2).Text
colum_c = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 3).Text
colum_d = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 4).Text
colum_e = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 5).Text
colum_f = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 6).Text
colum_g = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 7).Text
colum_h = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 8).Value
colum_i = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 9).Text
colum_j = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 10).Value
colum_k = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 11).Value
colum_l = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 12).Text
colum_m = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 13).Text
colum_n = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 14).Text
colum_o = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 15).Text
colum_p = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 16).Text
colum_q = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 17).Text
colum_r = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 18).Text
colum_s = Sheets(PD).Cells(k, 19).Value
   
             Set rs = e.Execute("INSERT INTO Pozadavky_Source_New (DATUM_ZADANI, ZADAVATEL, ID_POZADAVKU, RESITELSKY_TYM, KATEGORIE, NAZEV_POZADAVKU, STAV, DATUM_ODESLANI_KE_ZPRACOVANI, URGENTNI, TERMIN, DATUM_POSLEDNI_ZMENY, AUTOR_POSLEDNI_ZMENY, ZPETNY_KONTAKT_NA_KLIENTA, ZPETNY_KONTAKT_NA_KLIENTA_TYP, ZPETNY_KONTAKT_NA_KLIENTA_UDAJ, HISTORIE, ZDROJ, ID_ZDROJ, ID_POZADAVKU_SHORT) VALUES (" & colum_a & ", '" & colum_b & "', '" & colum_c & "', '" & colum_d & "', '" & colum_e & "', '" & colum_f & "', '" & colum_g & "', " & colum_h & ", '" & colum_i & "', " & colum_j & ", " & colum_k & ", '" & colum_l & "', '" & colum_m & "', '" & colum_n & "', '" & colum_o & "', '" & colum_p & "', '" & colum_q & "', '" & colum_r & "', " & colum_s & ")")
             
    End Sub
```

Thanks for reply, its very important to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show the final, complete insert query ? And please also show the schema of `Pozadavky_Source_New `

Comment: You're reading the `Value` property of your date cells, which is only going to give you the unformatted date.  Maybe take a look at the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775719/sql-datetime-insert-from-excel

Comment: What u mean as complete insert query? Table datatype of these columns is datetime, i tried datetime2(7) too.

Comment: They mean instead of passing the sql directly to `Execute`, put it in a variable and `Debug.Print` it to the Immediate window so you can include it in your post.

Comment: Well, fixed. Thanks Tim, problem was in inserting, like from your post. This works: VALUES ('" & Format(colum_a, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") & "', Thx again :)

Answer (score 0):

For example if column_k is a date I would type it like this

```
 Format(colum_k,"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

```
Set rs = e.Execute("INSERT INTO Pozadavky_Source_New (DATUM_ZADANI,ZADAVATEL, ID_POZADAVKU, RESITELSKY_TYM, KATEGORIE, NAZEV_POZADAVKU, STAV, DATUM_ODESLANI_KE_ZPRACOVANI, URGENTNI, TERMIN, DATUM_POSLEDNI_ZMENY, AUTOR_POSLEDNI_ZMENY, ZPETNY_KONTAKT_NA_KLIENTA, ZPETNY_KONTAKT_NA_KLIENTA_TYP, ZPETNY_KONTAKT_NA_KLIENTA_UDAJ, HISTORIE, ZDROJ, ID_ZDROJ, ID_POZADAVKU_SHORT) VALUES (" & colum_a & ", '" & colum_b & "', '" & colum_c & "', '" & colum_d & "', '" & colum_e & "', '" & colum_f & "', '" & colum_g & "', " & colum_h & ", '" & colum_i & "', " & colum_j & ", " & Format(colum_k,"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss") & ", '" & colum_l & "', '" & colum_m & "', '" & colum_n & "', '" & colum_o & "', '" & colum_p & "', '" & colum_q & "', '" & colum_r & "', " & colum_s & ")")
```